# Что за запись прототипа функции preg_replace в php manual?

Tags: php

```
mixed preg_replace (mixed pattern, mixed replacement, mixed string [, int limit [, int &$count]] );
```

что это `[, int limit [, int &$count]]` ? Как понимать вообще такую запись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)

> 1. необязательные параметры обозначаются квадратными скобками
>    вокруг себя?
> 2. А зачем тогда они вложены друг в друга? Я просто не видел вызов
>    preg_replace с 5 аргументами или же
>    его и нету с 5 аргументами, а они
>    вкладываются в третий.
> 3. Запятая как разделитель указывающий что есть ещё один параметр или же
>    что-то ещё? А зачем такая реализация?
>    Если вынести запятую вперед скобки, то
>    следующий параметр же не станет
>    массивом.

1. Да.
2. Если читать справа налево, становится ясно, что можно опустить либо только последний параметр, либо последний и предпоследний. Вариант с пропуском только предпоследнего - исключен. Попробуйте сократить скобки. Вычеркните визуально поочередно внешнюю и внутренние пары скобок. Вы не можете вычеркнуть предпоследний параметр, не порушив парность скобок. Возможно так станет понятнее.
   Как это не видели вызов с 5-ю аргументами? А как же упомянутая вами **[документация](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php#example-4869)**? По ссылке есть такой пример прямо в описании функции.
3. Запятая внутри скобок указывает на то, что ЭТОТ параметр необязательный, а те, что ему предшествуют (до первой открывающейся квадратной скобки) — обязательные.

Answer (score 0):

необязательные параметры

Comment: 1.необязательные параметры обозначаются квадратными скобками вокруг себя?
2. А зачем тогда они вложены друг в друга? Я просто не видел вызов preg_replace с 5 аргументами или же его и нету с 5 аргументами, а они вкладываются в третий. 
3. Запятая как разделитель указывающий что есть ещё один параметр или же что-то ещё? А зачем такая реализация? Если вынести запятую вперед скобки, то следующий параметр же не станет массивом.